# setTimeout function not working when looping through markers on Gmaps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, settimeout

I am trying to draw 50 markers in a row with 2 seconds in between each marker. The first marker gets drawn in GPS position (x, y) and then two seconds later, the second marker gets drawn in GPS position (x + 0.0004, y) and continues until the 50th marker is created on the map.

I have placed the marker constructor inside a setTimeout function. The setTimeout function is placed inside a for loop. However, when I run this, the loop runs through the 50 markers instantaneously (ie without the 2 second delay between each marker). Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

```
var map;
var longi = 174.7660981;

function initialize(){

    var mapProp = {
        //map properties
    };

    //create map object
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    //loop through setTimeout/Marker constructor
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8606873, longi),
                map: map
            });
            longi += 0.0004;
        }, 2000);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTimeout is working fine.  You are delaying all your markers by 2 seconds (the delay isn't between them).

```
var map;
var longi = 174.7660981;

function initialize(){

    var mapProp = {
        //map properties
    };

    //create map object
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    //loop through setTimeout/Marker constructor
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8606873, longi),
                map: map
            });
            longi += 0.0004;
        }, 2000*i);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```js
var map;
var longi = 174.7660981;

function initialize(){

    var mapProp = {
        center: {lat:0, lng:0},
      zoom: 15
    };

    //create map object
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    //loop through setTimeout/Marker constructor
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8606873, longi),
                map: map
            });
            longi += 0.0004;
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }, 2000*i);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
body, html, #googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: Ah I see! So the delay is accumulative - ie from the very first marker/starting point. Thanks heaps.